# unexpected response code 400 volley android

Tags: android, mysql

The code I've written is to connect my android studio to wamp server mysql. I try to retrieve login information from mysql to android. However it keep showing me unexpected response code 400. How should i change my code?

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
 getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
    loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, 
 false);

    //If we will get true
    if(loggedIn){
        //We will start the Profile Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
  PofileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void login(){
    //Getting values from edit texts
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
  Config.LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //If we are getting success from server
                    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                        //Creating a shared preference
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
 LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, 
 Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        //Creating editor to store values to shared 
 preferences
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
 sharedPreferences.edit();

                        //Adding values to editor
                        editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, 
 true);
                        editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                        //Saving values to editor
                        editor.commit();

                        //Starting profile activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
  PofileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        //If the server response is not success
                        //Displaying an error message on toast
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid username 
  or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    //You can handle error here if you want
                }
            }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Adding parameters to request
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

            //returning parameter
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Calling the login function
    login();
}
```

Comment: Is your API working as expected?

Comment: 400 means bad request. Are you passing the correct parameters? Also check for possible typos in url or parameters

Comment: can you post the url?

Comment: my url is http://192.168.1.2/apexStore2/user_login.php. Both my pc and mobile sharing the same internet connection however my mobile cannot connect to the web, it says i dont have permission to access the server. However by using emulator i can access but got error 400

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue when using volley library. You may not be setting the right headers when you are making the request that is why it gives us **400 Bad Request error.**

You may need to override the **getBodyContentType()** method in order to get the Content-Type header to update correctly.

```
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return "application/xml";
}
```

I have written a blog explaining the issue and how to resolve the same. Please refer [here](http://www.techstricks.com/android-volley-400-bad-request-resolved/) for resolution.